# How to remove white space in a string with Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, robotframework

My Variable : 54, 22

What I want : 54,22

I've tried :

> Execute Javascript var a = 54, 22;var x = a.split(' ').join('');return x

and

> Execute Javascript var a = 54, 22;var x = a.replace(/\s/g, '');return x

and

> log    ${str.strip()}

But none of them solved my problem. When I execute these code seperately I got that error:

> FAIL : WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected number\n    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:895:140)\n    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:828:34)\n    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)\n  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.124)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing commas in your variable, that's why you're getting syntax error:

```
var a = '54, 22';
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using the String Library

The [String library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) has a [Replace String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String) keyword that you can use to remove whitespace, without having to resort to running javascript:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | String

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of removing whitespace
| | ${value}= | Replace String | 54, 22 | ${space} | ${empty}
| | Should be equal | ${value} | 54,22
```

### Using the Evaluate keyword

You can run arbitrary python code with the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example of removing whitespace
| | ${value}= | Evaluate | "54, 22".replace(" ", "")
| | Should be equal | ${value} | 54,22
```